# Android send XML to PHP page

Tags: java, android, xml, post, content-type

I am trying to create an Android application in Java, and I need to send XML together with some other POST-information
It works, when the String do not contain the XML, and when it contains the XML only the POST-key for the XML is attached, not the content

I am sending the POST-information using the following code

```
// Check if there is nothing to input
if (input == null)
   input = new HashMap<String, String>();

// Add the mobile's ID
input.put("MobileID", ((TelephonyManager)cxt.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getDeviceId());

// The string for the input
String strInput = "";

// For each input
for (Entry<String, String> ent : input.entrySet()) {

   // Check if the string is not empty
   if (strInput.length() > 0)
      strInput += "&";

   // Add to the String
   strInput += URLEncoder.encode(ent.getKey(), Encoding.UTF_8.name()) + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ent.getValue(), Encoding.UTF_8.name());
}

// Open the connection and setup default values
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

// Set the RequestProperties
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization",  "Basic " + CtrSettings.getInstance().getAuthentication());
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", strInput.getBytes().length + "");

// Set the booleans for the connection
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);

// Create the input
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
dos.write(strInput.getBytes());
dos.flush();
dos.close();

// Return the connection
return conn;
```

Can anybody tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Am I missing something about a Content-Type or?

Another method could be to escape the XML to use inside another XML String, but I do not want PHP to recognize it as XML (and XML-tags) before I descape (or what word would it be?) it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now choosen to use `HttpPost` instead of `HttpsUrlConnection`, and that seems to do the job together with PHP's function `file_get_contents('php://input')`
I post this post here, so anyone else having trouble with it, can look at this post

Answer (score 0):

I guess your ContentType should be application/rss+xml

Gr